# find_in_set return different value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dow set('q','w','e','r','t','y', 'u') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;
```

With those values inside:

```
 id,   dow
'1', '1,3,6'
'1', '2,4,7'
```

Those query returns different values.

```
SELECT dow, FIND_IN_SET('4', dow) FROM (SELECT * from pippo.pluto) as B;

SELECT dow, FIND_IN_SET('4', dow) FROM pippo.pluto as B;
```

The first query returns those results:

```
'1,3,6', '0'
'2,4,7', '2'
```

The second query returns those results:

```
'1,3,6', '0'
'2,4,7', '4'
```

Why?

Tested against 5.6 and 5.7 mysql version.

Edit:

This behaviour remains the same if I use the mysql views.

```
CREATE VIEW selectInner AS SELECT dow, FIND_IN_SET('r', dow) FROM (SELECT * from pippo.foobar) as B;
CREATE VIEW selectDirect AS SELECT dow, FIND_IN_SET('r', dow) FROM pippo.foobar as B;
```

Comment: What values do they return?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: My guess would be that this gets messed up due to the weird combination of using the decimal equivalents of your actual set values in FIND_IN_SET, and that `SELECT from (SELECT * FROM)` probably changes how the data is actually returned. Please test if this behaves differently if you use FIS to actually check for one of the _letters_ that your set contains.

Comment: As documentation suggests (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) the return value is always between 1 and the number of substrings described as second parameter.
'4' value should be never considered as a valid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things interacting here:

- "If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type `SET`, the `FIND_IN_SET()` function is optimized to use bit arithmetic." per [`FIND_IN_SET` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
- One of the two queries operates directly on the table, and the second on a derived table.

The behaviour demonstrates this:

- When operating directly on the table (where `dow` refers to the defined column in that table's metadata), `FIND_IN_SET` returns the index of the entry in the column's *definition*
- When operating on a derived table (where `dow` refers to a derived column), `FIND_IN_SET` returns the index of the entry in the derived *value*

This is clear if you search for e.g. `y` and `u` in a column containing `q,e,y,u`: you'd get 6 and 7 when querying the table directly, where `dow` is a `SET` containing `q,w,e,r,t,y,u` and `FIND_IN_SET` uses bitwise optimizations; but 3 and 4 when searching the derived table, where `dow` is the string containing `q,e,y,u` for that row.